# Google Dataprep Date Serial Number

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataprep

In Google Dataprep when I apply min() to a date it gives a long serial number e.g. 1304985600000. I'm trying to get the first order date of a customer but I can't seem to do anything with this number

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a UNIX timestamp represented in milliseconds. With this value in BigQuery, simply do:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP_MILLIS(1304985600000)
```

Output:

```
Row f0_  
1   2011-05-10 00:00:00.000 UTC
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the unix timestamp to a Date in Cloud Dataprep using the `UNIXTIMEFORMAT` function: https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/html/UNIXTIMEFORMAT-Function_57344709